# Can't load image file in asp.net : System.IO.FileNotFoundException HResult=0x80070002 Message=data-science.png

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to load images from my computer to sql database when web application starts but I can't load image data to vb. It is giving file not found exception even though file path is right.

```
Sub Application_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim imgpaths As Array = {"crslogo\data-science.png", "crslogo\python.jpg", "crslogo\acc.jpg"}
    MsgBox(imgpaths(0))

    Dim bArr As Array = {}
    For i = 0 To imgpaths.Length - 1
        Dim img As Image = Image.FromFile("crslogo\data-science.png")
        bArr(i) = imgToByteArray(img)
    Next
End Sub
```

[`image`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ys0F1.png)

Comment: You are using relative paths. What is your current working dir?

Comment: @derpirscher thanks . After inserting absolute path no error was given.

Comment: Give you arrays a datatype `Dim imgpaths() As String = ...` and `Dim bArr() As Byte =...`